# How to do calculations with array list elements.?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, integer

I have an integer array list. It will always contain 5 integers. Now suppose it contains the numbers 10031. Now I want to do this calculation in the elements.

Add the numbers within this number, until you are left with a 1 or 2 digit number.

> 1.....0.....0.....3.....1
>
> ...1.....0......3....4
>
> .......1.....3.....7
>
> ...........4....10 (When this occurs, separate into 1 + 0)
>
> ..............5..1 = 51. Result is 51.

I want the result when it is a double digit number. Please help.

Comment: Personally I'd prefer you showed some effort first; can you post what you have that *doesn't* work? it's also not clear to me what the actual computation rules are.

Comment: @DaveNewton it's like a pascal triangle downwards except you need to slice two-digit numbers into two one-digit numbers, and if you have 2 or 1 numbers left with this scheme then merge the two numbers into one and you'll get a number - is my guess.

Comment: This is basically just list manipulation, if you're allowed to have a second `temporary` list into which you calculate the new result and then replace the original then it's actually surprisingly easy - you just add `i` and `i+1`, add to the other list, check if you have numbers that are bigger than 10, split those into two numbers (divide first by 10 then add the remainder as a new element after that element), then check if you have 2 or less elements in the list, and if yes then just make a number out of them being 5*10 + 1. This feels like an assignment, and I'm sure you can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static int yourFunction(ArrayList<Integer> list){
    String numbers = ""; // fill a string with your numbers

    for(Integer i : list){
        numbers += String.valueOf(i);
    } // could be nicer with java8 lambda function


    String tmp_numbers; // temporary string needed
    while(numbers.length() > 2){
        tmp_numbers = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length()-1; ++i){
            // add two following numbers
            // substring to read digit by digit
            int v = Integer.parseInt(numbers.substring(i,i+1)); // first digit
                v += Integer.parseInt(numbers.substring(i+1,i+2)); // + second
            tmp_numbers = tmp_numbers + String.valueOf(v); // and fill the tmp string with it
        }
        numbers = tmp_numbers; // set the tmp string to our new beginning
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be better for you if you resolved this task by your own but it's your choice. 
All explanations in comments.

```
public static int countTriangle(List<Integer> list) {
    if (list.size() == 0) {
        //  if list is empty return 0
        return 0;
    } else if (list.size() == 1) {
        //  if list contains only single element return this element
        return list.get(0);
    } else if (list.size() == 2) {
        //  if list contains two elements, return them connected
        //  for example we have list of 5 and 1
        //  we multiple 5 with 10 (50) and then add 1 to it,
        //  so the output of 5 and 1 will be 51
        return list.get(0) * 10 + list.get(1);
    }
    //  create new list for the next triangle's line
    List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //  iterate over every element of existing list
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        //  a = current element + next element (last iteration will be with last but one element)
        int a = list.get(i) + list.get(i+1);
        //  if a has two digits or more
        if (a >= 10) {
            //  translate it to String
            String s = String.valueOf(a);
            //  take every char of a String, translate it to number and add to new list
            //  for example if a = 157 then three new elements will be added to new list (1, 5, 7)
            for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
                newList.add(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(s.charAt(j))));
            }
        //  if a has single digit
        } else {
            //  add this to new list
            newList.add(a);
        }
    }
    //  call this function with new list (next line)
    return countTriangle(newList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void test() {
    ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    test.add(1);
    test.add(0);
    test.add(0);
    test.add(3);
    test.add(1);
    ArrayList<Integer> ret = doTheMagic(test);
    for (Integer i : ret)
        System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(transformInDigit(ret));
}

private int transformInDigit(final ArrayList<Integer> values) {
    int ret = 0;
    int size = values.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)         
        ret+=values.get(i)*Math.pow(10, size-i-1);
    return ret;
}

private ArrayList<Integer> doTheMagic(final ArrayList<Integer> values) {
    int size = values.size();
    if (size<=2)
        return values;
    ArrayList<Integer> ret = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        Integer newVal = values.get(i)+values.get(i+1);
        if (newVal < 10)
            ret.add(newVal);
        else {
            ret.add(newVal / 10);
            ret.add(newVal % 10);
        }
    }
    return doTheMagic(ret);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have always the same amount of numbers, you can do that without a loop.
At the first step, you calculate the first element + the second and save the result in the first index of a new array. Then the second + the third one and the result in the second index of the new array. And so on. Then you do the same thing with the results in the new array, until you have the result.

Also you have to calculate the cross sum after every calculation. For this purpose you can do something like this:

```
public int crossSum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
        while(n > 0) {
            int digit = n%10;
            sum += digit;
            n /= 10;
        }
    return sum;
 }`
```

In the last step, you don't calculate the cross sum. When there is only one digit, you display the result with a zero in front of it. So you get a two-digit result.